# get value of cell in focused row in grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to get the value of  a cell  in the focused row, but it doesn't work.

```
function OnGridFocusedRowChanged() {
        gvUserGroups.GetRowValues(gvUserGroups.GetFocusedRowIndex(), 'NAME', OnGetRowValues);
    }

function OnGetRowValues(values) {
        alert(values[0].toString());
    }
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: You should provide more information about library you are using to create grid. I assume it's DevExpress ASP.NET Grid View Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function you are supplying only one field *NAME*, so GetRowValues won't return an array.

Try this:

```
function OnGetRowValues(value) {
        alert(value.toString());
    }
```

I tested this on [demo page](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Rows/FocusedRow.aspx) with Firebug and it worked well.